# Export all MySQL users

Tags: mysql, users, permissions

I need export all of a MySQL database users (including permissions) for a migration. There is over 5,000 users, what is the best way to do this?

Should I just dump the `mysql.user` table?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are moving the users to another DB Server running the same major version of MySQL, copying `mysql.user` is not sufficient. If the users have access to specific databases, copying `mysql.user` brings the user and the password.

Then, you would have to copy the following

- `mysql.db` for database-level grants
- `mysql.tables_priv` for table-level grants
- `mysql.columns_priv` for column-level grants

Here is logical way to dump it: as SQL GRANT commands !!!

## SUGGESTION #1

If you already have Percona Toolkit installed, run [pt-show-grants](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-show-grants.html) to a text file

```
GRANT_FILE=MyDatabaseUSers.sql
pt-show-grants -uroot -p > ${GRANT_FILE}
```

## SUGGESTION #2

If you don't have Percona Toolkit and can't wait, here is my personal emulation of it

```
GRANT_CMDS=/tmp/ShowGrantsToExport.sql
GRANT_FILE=MyDatabaseUSers.sql
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
SQL="SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ',QUOTE(user),'@',QUOTE(host),';')"
SQL="${SQL} FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>'' AND host<>''"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}" > ${GRANT_CMDS}
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} < ${GRANT_CMDS} | sed 's/$/;/g' > ${GRANT_FILE}
```

## EPILOGUE

On the new DB Server, after migrating the data, you login to mysql as root and run

```
mysql> source MyDatabaseUSers.sql
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Thanks so much. `pt-show-grants -uroot -p > ${GRANT_FILE}` worked perfectly.

Comment: Useful! I think you have to add the `-N` also in the last mysql command.

Comment: Thank you so much @RolandoMySQLDBA!  You second suggestion has helped me extract user information from a  broken system that had backed up with `mysqldump` but where the latest version of MySQL no longer recognizes restoring a `mysql.user` table.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the above script by Rolando, but more concise and unix-ish. Just pass your options on the command as you would MySQL. It outputs to stdout. The output can be fed directly back into mysql.

```
#!/bin/sh
mysql -AN <<'SQL' "$@" | mysql "$@" | sed 's/$/;/;/^Grants for /d'

SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ',QUOTE(user),'@',QUOTE(host),';')
FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>'' AND host<>''
ORDER BY user, host
;

SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the MySQL tool : [mysqluserclone](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.6/en/mysqluserclone.html)

```
mysqluserclone  --source=root:PASSWORD@localhost --list -d
```

You will get a list of all users and the corresponding `GRANT` statements.

You could also use `--destination` parameter if you have remote access to your new database.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to thank John K. N. for mentioning mysqluserclone.  Unfortunately, it's not available as a package for Ubuntu 20.04 due to python 2 being deprecated but I did find a workaround [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246640/unable-to-install-mysqldiff-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/192569)