# Migrating all MySQL databases from from one server another. Getting error during import

Tags: mysql, backup, restore, mysqldump

1. I create a mysqldump on all the databases on the source server with this command:

> mysqldump -h mysql-01 -u root -p --all-databases > newdump.sql

This takes about an hour, but runs fine.

2. Now, to migrate the data of the dump file on the destination server I run this:

> mysql -h mysql-vm-01 -u root -p < newdump.sql

all seems to be going fine for like 30 minutes and then I get this error

> **ERROR 1449 (HY000) at line 100083 : The user specified as a definer ('dc_reporter'@'%') does not exist.**

What should I do ??

Comment: Try the answers posed in this other question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169960/mysql-error-1449-the-user-specified-as-a-definer-does-not-exist

Comment: I have already tried what the others posts have suggested. But with no luck . So now I am posting my question here.

Comment: Run suitable `GRANTs` before trying to reload.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should dump the users and load the users into the VM

Here is my post : [Export all MySQL users](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95928/export-all-mysql-users/95933#95933)

After running the code in it and saving it to a file called `MyDatabaseUSers.sql`, you log into mysql on the VM and run this:

```
mysql> source MyDatabaseUSers.sql
```

This will create all the users with the same grants and passwords. Don't worry: Passwords are encrypted.

After importing the users, you should be able to reload the mysqldump.

**GIVE IT A TRY !!!**

NOTE: If you loaded all your data successfully, the error might have occurred loading a MySQL object that has a DEFINER associated with it

- stored procedures
- triggers
- views
- events.

Do the following:

```
cat newdump.sql | grep -A 2 -n "dc_reporter"
```

This will show you what might not have loaded. Your data may all be there.

You could try dumping your stored procedures and triggers and reloading them instead of reloading everything. Please read my old post [Can mysqldump dump triggers and procedures?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6420/can-mysqldump-dump-triggers-and-procedures/6423#6423), go dump your triggers and stored procedures, and reload them into the VM. If you have views to import, please read my old post [Modify DEFINER on Many Views](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/modify-definer-on-many-views) and use the code to mysqldump just the views.