# mysqldump all database including user/password and grants

Tags: mysql, backup, mariadb

I am running `10.5.12-MariaDB` and trying to take full backup of all databases including user accounts/ passwords and Grants but somehow i am not able to take backup of grants so am i missing something.

Example.

Taking full backup

```
old-DB # mysqldump --opt --all-databases > /root/openstack.sql
```

Restoring to new DB server

```
new-DB # mysql < openstack.sql
```

Now i can see all databases and all users in `mysql.user` table but grants are missing for all users.

example:

```
old-DB # mysql -e 'show grants for glance';
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for glance@%                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `glance`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*6FE1E5E532A9189C900FB696AC9DEF84CDE2194A' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `glance`.* TO `glance`@`%`                                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Its missing on new DB server

```
new-DB# mysql -e 'show grants for glance';
ERROR 1141 (42000) at line 1: There is no such grant defined for user 'glance' on host '%'
```

So i did following

```
old-DB# mysql --skip-column-names -A -e"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ''',user,'''@''',host,''';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''" | mysql --skip-column-names -A | sed 's/$/;/g' > MySQLUserGrants.sql
```

Now MySQLUserGrants.sql has all the users grants command so i just copy paste all command and paste to new-DB i got following error

```
MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `glance`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*6FE1E5E532A9189C900FB696AC9DEF84CDE2194A';
ERROR 1133 (28000): Can't find any matching row in the user table
```

Question, how do i take full mysql backup which include everything even including grants. (or am i missing something?)

Comment: Damn it, `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` fixed my issue and now i can use `GRANT` command without error. but still is there any good way to take backup of grant using mysqldump?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can use the `--system` switch. This exists only in the MariaDB version of `mysqldump`, although you can use that to dump from a MySQL database.

`system=users` will dump `CREATE USER ...` and `GRANT ...` statements for your users and grants:

```
mysqldump --opt --system=users --insert-ignore --all-databases > /root/openstack.sql
```

The `--insert-ignore` option is important to avoid conflicts with existing users when importing the dump. The option will result in `CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS` statements rather than just `CREATE USER`.

To *really* include everything, use instead `--system=all`.

See documentation in the MariaDB KB [mysqldump](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqldump/) and the [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mysqldump.1.html) (search for `--system`).

This is a recent feature which has been backported to MariaDB 10.2 and later versions.

Comment: I got this error when i restore `ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 16339: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'mariadb.sys'@'localhost'`

Comment: Apologizes, there's still a couple of bugs I need to fix. As you are merging into a fresh instances I suggest using `--insert-ignore` in the dump which will avoid the issue with the user `mariadb.sys`. Be very careful if you use `--replace` means that a new import user that doesn't exist in the dump is needed for the import (MDEV-25537).

Comment: @danblack The man page (in the section for `--system`) says to use `--insert-into`, but that doesn't seem to be a recognized option! So I guess it's `--insert-ignore` as you say. Anyway, the `--system=` feature is awesome, thanks for implementing it.

Comment: yep. `--insert-ignore`. Glad you like it. Thanks for answering with it. Happy to take bug reports/feature requests.

Comment: And [fixing spelling mistakes](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/tree/bb-10.2-wrong-word-mysqldump).

Comment: @danblack ah, I reported it as a bug - MDEV-26622 - superfluous now!

Comment: is there a non-mariadb way to do it? Using Oracle mysqldump?

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty much doing the right thing with backing up the grants logically.

I recommended that same way about 7.5 years ago : [Export all MySQL users](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95928/export-all-mysql-users/95933#95933)

You can also use [pt-show-grants](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-show-grants.html) and append `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` to the output

```
(
   pt-show-grants ...
   echo "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
) > user_grants.sql
```

Comment: So i have to install `percona-toolkit` for pt-show-grants command to just dump grants, in that case i would use my method which has no dependency

Comment: Yes. That is why I posted both methods years ago.

Comment: There may be one problem. You might have MairaDB configured not to create users. Run `SELECT @@global.sql_mode`. If you see `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER`, then you must also include the `CREATE USER` command for each user. A possible workaround might be to run `SEt sql_mode='';` before executing your grants file.

Comment: Older version of MySQL/MariaDB will automatically create the user when you issue `GRANT USAGE ... PASSWORD ...`. Newer versions require making the user first or blanking out `sql_mode`.